# How to execute the jquery method in aspx before the method in usercontrol registered for same event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a usercontrol which contains a textbox in it. The Pageload method of usercontrol set on blur function in the control.

```
txtZip.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "getCities('"txtZip.ClientID"');
```

I have used the this usercontrol in my page and added the another method for same event in jquery.

```
  function pageLoad() {
        $jQuery("[id$=txtZip]").on("blur", function () {
            //Some logic
        });
    }
```

But ***getCities*** method execute first before method in Page. How can i call this method before ***getCities*** method.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function pageLoad() {
        $jQuery("[id$=txtZip]").on("blur", function () {
            //Some logic
            getCities($("[id$=txtZip]").attr("id"));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: the OP wants to excute the method getCities when txtZip is blured, but after the execution of "Some logic" . Thats waht will happen. $("[id$=txtZip]").attr("id") wiil get the value of txtZip.ClientID.